# ¿Como obtener los datos dentro del array?

Tags: php, laravel

Cordial saludo para todos, necesito obtener el valor "providerManual":true, para poder hacer una validación y trabajar con el proveedor, pero no he podido.

Este arreglo llega de la variable `$aGet['groupData']`

Intente algo como esto pero no funciona:

```
$provider = $aGet['groupData']['providerManual'];
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```
{
   "unit":{
      "id":"UNIDADES",
      "name":"UNIDADES"
   },
   "currency":"COP",
   "providersList":[
      {
         "PROID":"11111111",
         "PRONA":"nnnnn",
         "VALP":"10",
         "TOTP":10
      }
   ],
   "approve":false,
   "providerManual":true,
   "product":{
      "ITPR":"123",
      "ITPD":"MEMORIA USB 16 GB.",
      "VALP":"00",
      "TOTP":0
   },
   "loadingProvider":false,
   "provider":{
      "PROID":"11111111",
      "PRONA":"nnnnn",
      "VALP":"10",
      "TOTP":10
   },
   "number":3,
   "cost":"1",
   "sub_cost":"2",
   "usidauth":{
      "USRI":"NNN",
      "USRN":"LEIDY ",
      "CARI":"6",
      "CARD":"LIDER"
   },
   "observations":"nada",
   "invoice":"PRUEBA_R"
}
```

Comment: Qué es lo que obtienes si haces un var_dump()?

Comment: Puedes agregar mas información para conocer el contexto. Y si se puede, código. De favor.

Comment: tienes que ayudar con un poco mas de informacion, tal cual asi te regresa el array?

Comment: si con `$aGet['groupData']` te llega un json, primero tendras que decodificarlo, no? prueba con un json_decode$aGet['groupData'], true) para decodificarlo, y luego a ese array que te devuelve intentas acceder a su clave `providerManual`

Comment: @Jakala muchas gracias por la recomendación y si, efectivamente tuve que decodificarlo para poder acceder a la propiedad `providerManual`.


`$data = json_decode($aGet['groupData']);
    if ($typeProvider = $data->providerManual) {
      $valueProvider = $data->provider->PROITIDX;
    } else {
      $valueProvider = $data->PROVESERV->PROITIDX;
    }
`

Y así puede evaluar si era falso y que me devolviera el nit del proveedor